# Deobfuscating algorithm used on "free robux" scam website

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, deobfuscation

Today I have been trying to analyse the code behind a website used for scams that involve the online game called Roblox
this is a domain called buxgenerator.com

This domain uses the all too common scam that involves using surveys that collect personal data by sending the victims who are typically young gullible children to this link https://cpbild.co/93c0cd5

They are eventually told they need to solve the "human verification " which is scammer talk for surveys that collect your personal data

By using a free html code analyser app I was able to view the following code of the website https://pastebin.com/sc0inEv8

The interesting thing I found out is a small portion of the code is obfuscated by an unknown algorithm

```
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
```

I have been unsuccessful in finding information regarding the origin ip address of the scammer so I hope deobfuscating this algorithm will perhaps help me get closer to my goal which is to find out where this website is actually located.

Comment: `atob(/* your mystic string */)`

Answer (score 1):

That's base64 encoded JSON.

The payload is

```
{"call_to_action":"GET V-BUCKS","description":"Roblox Free Robux Generator. Special request to create a new generator for free unlimited Robux.","google_analytics":"UA-00000-0","keywords":"Roblox Free Robux Generator","menu_header":"Select Amount of V-Bucks","platform_field":"Your Platform","redirect_url":"https:\/\/google.com","select_button":"Select","title":"Roblox Robux Generator | Get Free Robux","username_field":"Your username","verification_button":"Verify Now","verification_name":"Anti-Bot Verification","verification_title":"VERIFICATION","cents_required":"20","leads_required":"2","offers_amount":"6","faster_generator":"0","tix_on":"0","has_header":"1","generator_on":"1","sounds_on":"1","chat_on":"1","verification_header":"Anti-Bot Verification","verification_text":"Complete any 2 offers to verify","voucher_name":"Card"}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you shared, I noticed that the long string there is put through a function named `atob()`. After further research, `atob` basically converts base64 into a string. Using a base64 decoder, I found it to be a JSON string with the following content:

```
{"call_to_action":"GET V-BUCKS","description":"Roblox Free Robux Generator. Special request to create a new generator for free unlimited Robux.","google_analytics":"UA-00000-0","keywords":"Roblox Free Robux Generator","menu_header":"Select Amount of V-Bucks","platform_field":"Your Platform","redirect_url":"https:\/\/google.com","select_button":"Select","title":"Roblox Robux Generator | Get Free Robux","username_field":"Your username","verification_button":"Verify Now","verification_name":"Anti-Bot Verification","verification_title":"VERIFICATION","cents_required":"20","leads_required":"2","offers_amount":"6","faster_generator":"0","tix_on":"0","has_header":"1","generator_on":"1","sounds_on":"1","chat_on":"1","verification_header":"Anti-Bot Verification","verification_text":"Complete any 2 offers to verify","voucher_name":"Card"}
```

I hope that answers your question :)

## Edit

Also, after reading the code further, this scam just asks you for 'leads' and 'cents' and once you give enough (at `cents_required` and `leads_required` in the JSON), it redirects you to some webpage. In `redirect_url`, it shows 'google.com', but I think that they change it to something else.